# Match everything up until first instance of a colon

Tags: r, regex

Trying to code up a Regex in R to match everything before the first occurrence of a colon.

Let's say I have:

```
time = "12:05:41"
```

I'm trying to extract just the 12.  My strategy was to do something like this:

```
grep(".+?(?=:)", time, value = TRUE)
```

But I'm getting the error that it's an invalid Regex.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex seems fine in my opinion, I don't think you should use grep, also you are missing `perl=TRUE` that is why you are getting the error.

I would recommend using :

```
stringr::str_extract( time, "\\d+?(?=:)")
```

grep is little different than it is being used here, its good for matching separate values and filtering out those which has similar pattern, but you can't pluck out values within a string using grep.

If you want to use Base R you can also go for `sub`:

```
sub("^(\\d+?)(?=:)(.*)$","\\1",time, perl=TRUE)
```

Also, you may split the string using strsplit and filter out the first string like below:

```
strsplit(time, ":")[[1]][1]
```

Comment: Good call on all accounts.  Thanks!